# Why is nothing happening when I click my "Send Email" menu item?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, menu, menuitem

I'm writing a recipe book, and I've encountered a problem - when I click my menu item, which is supposed to send email, with email address and subject pre-filled, nothing happens ...

Any ideas why ???

```
public class recipedisplayscreen extends Activity {

TextView EmailAddress;

TextView EmailSubject;

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recipedisplayscreen);

        TextView MethodDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView IngredientsDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        String Ingredients = i.getStringExtra("textView1");
        String Method = i.getStringExtra("textView2");
        Log.e("recipedisplayscreen", Ingredients + "." + Method);

        MethodDisplay.setText(Method);
        IngredientsDisplay.setText(Ingredients);

        EmailAddress=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        EmailSubject=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 


        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        setTitle(R.string.title);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle(Method);}

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    // App icon in action bar clicked; go home
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected1(MenuItem recipe_suggest) {
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ EmailAddress.getText().toString()}); 
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EmailSubject.getText()); 

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            return true;
        }




     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu1, menu);
            return true;         
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want :D delete **onOptionsItemSelected1** and replace *onOptionsItemSelected* with this, this is assuming that recipe_suggest is the menu item's id?

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // App icon in action bar clicked; go home
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.recipe_suggest:
                //Other menu item I believe
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{                 EmailAddress.getText().toString()}); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EmailSubject.getText()); 

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

What a switch does is match the object in the "switch" to the case, the case that matches the "switch" gets carried out, so if the menu item id (MenuItem item; item.getItemId()) matches the ID either android.R.id.home or R.id.recipe_suggest (I assume you are using the action bar as you are referring to the Android R file?) this is how it should be done to the best of my knowlegde :)

Comment: the thing is that MenuItem item and Menu Item recipe_suggest are two different menus ?

Comment: A item is what the method *onOptionsItemSelected* receives, the object type of item is MenuItem, item holds the basic information about what was pressed, whether it was the home button or any item in the menu this method in theory should still be called by the framework.

Comment: recipe_suggest is an item, its the "ID" that you need to refer to, recipe_suggest is part of a XML file correct? It's an item in recipe_menu1 correct? with the ID recipe_suggest correct? When you build the project the ID is "stored" in the R file and has a "reference" int attached to it as such with the name recipe_suggest inside the sub class id which inside the class R, the class R is what you reference which you then reference the class id which holds the value recipe_suggest, the int that it holds is matched with the int that the menu item that is attached to the call. :D sorry for the

Comment: No problem :D Android is a passion, I strive to help people out and teach them, if I can give someone my knowledge then they can pass it to others which will in turn pass it to another. Give knowledge to two and they each can pass it on to two others creating a vast school of knowledge :D

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two onOptionsItemSelected? Well, one is called onOptionsItemSelected**1** , need to merge that into the real one.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just create a method called `onOptionsItemSelected1()` and expect that android calls it when you hit the menu entry to send the mail.

Merge this method to the original `onOptionsItemSelected()` and put it in the right case, than it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a separate method called onOptionsItemSelected**1** ?

All the code reacting to action items should be in **onOptionsItemSelected** :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // App icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        case android.R.id.email_action_item:

            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            (...)
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```